# Contacting User Regarding Deleted Question

Tags: discussion, support

I nominated a question for closing as being off-topic, and the user commented, asking which se site was the best place to ask the question, and then deleted the question.
I didn't want to vote to reopen the question just to comment and then vote to delete again...so I'm not sure how to perform due diligence here.
I'm not seeking personal information for contact, that's out of line, and also not applicable to all.
Is there a way to do this?
I thought of chat, but they would have to be in chat as well...
Edit:
Original post included a link to Open Data SE's chat room, not the question that has been deleted.

Comment: Your link points to our chat room ;) If you could point me to the deleted question, I'll look into it …

Comment: doh! how did i miss that!?!?! thanks for pointing that out....and now I cannot find the question. I've looked through my history from 2016-04-02 and I cannot find a trace of it. I'm assuming this is because its deleted?

Comment: I found the question and left a comment pointing him to this discussion.

Comment: thank you! how/where did you find it?